# Change html numeric min and max with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

changeI have two numeric inputs and would like to limit the max or min of the second one based on the changes of the first one. So....

```
 <input id="input1" type="number" min="0" max="10" value="5" change="OnChangeNumeric()" >
 <input id="input2" type="number" min="0" max="10" value="1" >

 <script>

 function OnChangeNumeric() {

 //how to actually change the values is where i am stuck

 $('#input2').max = 5;
 }
 </script>
```

how to actually change the values is where i am stuck

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Care to share what you have tried with us? You don't give any rules for if changing A to something B should be this.

Comment: Are you using Jquery?

Comment: Do you know how to select the elements you want to change? If not you should start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById You might also want to check docs on how to change attributes on an element... Without more info on what exactly is causing the confusion you're not going to get much more information.

Comment: I think that when input one changes I would like to change input2.max to 5 lets say. I think I need to use jquery to do this but if I don't need to that is acceptable also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#input1').on('change',function() {
        var thisVal = this.value;
        /*calculate newMin, and newMax for #input2 according to your rules
          based on thisVal ........
        $('#input2').attr('min', newMin).attr('max', newMax);*/
        console.log( $('#input2')[0] );
    });
});
```

No need for inline JS:

```
<input id="input1" type="number" min="0" max="10" value="5"/>
<input id="input2" type="number" min="0" max="10" value="1"/>
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/qvVMa/)